# How do i install less css compiler?

Tags: command-line, compiler, css, npm, less

I just installed less css compiler using `npm`. Now the`lessc`file directory is `/usr/local/bin/lessc` . i'm not clear what i need to change in `lessc` file and how to understand that compiler has been correctly installed.

Answer (score 9):

- To Install Less Compiler

  ```
  sudo npm install -g less
  ```
- To know the location of it

  ```
  sudo which lessc
  ```
- To compile ".less" File to ".css"

  ```
  lessc /home/--Your LESS File Location--/File.less > /home/--Your CSS File Location--/main.css
  ```

Answer (score 5):

`/usr/local/bin/` should already be in your `$PATH` so there's nothing to do.

Simply use `lessc` like you would any other command. Here's a little snippet showing mine is installed like yours, and it parsing some LESS into CSS.

```
$ sudo npm install -g less
... npm installs less ...

$ which lessc
/usr/local/bin/lessc

$ lessc - <<< 'a{color:white; strong {color:black}}'
a {
  color: white;
}
a strong {
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: its not working. Please suggest me, which line should  change in "lessc" file. i am not sure but seem something need to change in my "lessc" file.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. You shouldn't need to change *anything* in the lessc file. Please edit your question to show what you see when you run the command.

Comment: @NajimSujon What exactly do you mean by 'Not Working'?

Answer (score 2):

Installation:

```
sudo apt install node-less
```

Using:

```
lessc source_file.less file.css
```